# The curvature of a plane curve with polar coordinate

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, plane-curves, curvature

let a plane curve with polar coordinates ( $\theta$ , $\rho (\theta )$) and let $k(\theta)$ be it's curvature one can preuve that

> $k(\theta) = \frac{2({\rho }')^{2}-\rho {\rho }''+ \rho ^{2}}{({\rho }'^{2}+\rho ^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}} $

we can do this with some calculation ,but i need method with less calculation possible.

thank you for help .

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation for curvature is somewhat simpler in complex variables. Namely, if $z=r(\theta)e^{i\theta}$, then

$$\kappa(\theta)=\frac{\mathfrak{Im}\{\dot z^*\ddot z\}}{|\dot z|^3}$$

where $\dot z=dz/d\theta~$ and $()^*$ is the conjugate. Of course, in the final analysis both must be the same, but if you're doing this in a program, then this is much simpler.

Comment: Nice.  Love to see the derivation!

Comment: It's from one of my most trusted resources: Zwikker, C. (1968). *The Advanced Geometry of Plane Curves and Their Applications*, Dover Press. It's available online here: alexandria.tue.nl/repository/books/475961.pdf. You'll find it on p. 30. It's totally in the complex plane. Have fun.

Comment: @RobertLewis Sorry, I forgot to put your address on the reply above-want to make sure you get it.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks!

Comment: I you put a derivation in a separate answer, I'll upvote it! 

Comment: @RobertLewis Robert, the derivation is posted on this page. Thanks for your interest. Always glad to help out my younger colleagues!

Comment: Thanks so much.  By the way, I was able to download the book; looks fascinating!

Comment: @RobertLewis It's one of my two favorite references. The other is K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, *An Atlas of Functions*, 2nd Ed., Springer. (I also have the 1st edition; I've had it for years.) Another reference I frequently reach for is the CRC *Standard Mathematical Tables and Formulae* (various editions). Lots of information and relatively easy to find.

Answer (score 5):

@RobertLewis has requested a derivation of the expression for curvature that I gave in my other answer. This is sufficiently more involved to warrant a separate answer.

There are several things to understand before we can do the derivation proper:

1. The argument of a complex number. Consider that

$$z=|z|e^{i\theta},\quad z^*=|z|e^{-i\theta}$$

then

$$\frac{z}{z^*}=e^{2i\theta}\quad \text{or}\quad e^{i\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{z}{z^*}}\quad \text{or}\quad \theta=\frac{1}{2i}\ln\frac{z}{z^*}$$

You can verify this for yourself. Start with $\ln z=\ln |z|+i\theta$.

2. The curvature, $\kappa$ is defined in terms of the tangent angle, $\tau$ and the arc length, $s$ by Euler's integral solution for plane curves,

$$\tau =\int{\kappa \left( s \right)\,ds;\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,{d\tau }/{ds=\kappa \left( s \right)}\;}\\
\kappa(\theta)=\frac{d\tau}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{ds}$$

where $\theta$ is the polar angle. We also know that for any parametric representation, the arc length is given by

$$
s=\int |\dot z|du\\
\frac{ds}{du}=|\dot z|=\sqrt{\dot z\dot z^*}
$$

3. We can now pull this all together to derive the curvature in terms of the polar angle. First, however, we must realize that the tangent angle is equal to the argument of the derivative of the curve, i.e.,

$$
\begin{align}
\tau(\theta)
&=\frac{d\tau}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{ds}\\
&=\frac{1}{2i}\ln\frac{\dot z}{\dot z^*}
\end{align}
$$

Then

$$
\begin{align}
\tau(\theta)
&=\arg \dot z\\
\kappa(\theta)
&=\frac{1}{2i}\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\ln\frac{\dot z}{\dot z^*}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\dot z\dot z^*}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2i}\frac{d}{d\theta}(\ln\dot z-\ln\dot z^*)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\dot z\dot z^*}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{\ddot z}{\dot z}-\frac{\ddot z^*}{\dot z^*}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\dot z\dot z^*}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2i}\frac{\dot z^*\ddot z-\dot z\ddot z^*}{(\dot z\dot z^*)^{3/2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2i}\frac{\dot z^*\ddot z-(\dot z^*\ddot z)^*}{(\dot z\dot z^*)^{3/2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2i}\frac{2i\mathfrak{Im}\{\dot z^*\ddot z\}}{(\dot z\dot z^*)^{3/2}}\quad \text{since}\quad Z-Z^*=2i\mathfrak{Im}\{Z\}\\
&=\frac{\mathfrak{Im}\{\dot z^*\ddot z\}}{|\dot z|^3}
\end{align}
$$

This completes the derivation.

Comment: @RobertLewis I have just determined that saying $\arg Z=\frac{1}{2i}\ln (Z/Z^*)$ can get you into the same problems as taking $\tan$ as opposed to $\text{tan2}$ in some situations. To be on the safe side, you should always use $\arg Z=\frac{1}{2i}(\ln Z−\ln Z^∗)$.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is not to be scared of making long calculations.

You may have encountered the following proposition

> The curvature of a plane curve $\alpha(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ is given by the $$\kappa(t)=\dfrac{x'y''-x''y'}{((x')^2+(y')^2)^{3/2}}$$

Consider the polar curve $\rho = \rho(\theta)$ and your parametrization in cartesian coordinates $\alpha(\theta)=\rho(\theta)\left(\cos\theta,\sin\theta\right)$ from that we get
\begin{align*}
  \alpha'(\theta)&=(x'(\theta),y'(\theta))=\rho'(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)+\rho(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)\\
  \alpha''(\theta)&=(x''(\theta),y''(\theta))=(\rho''-\rho)(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)+2\rho'(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)
 \end{align*}
In this way,

\begin{align*}
x'(\theta)y''(\theta)&=(\rho'\cos\theta-\rho\sin\theta)[(\rho''-\rho)\sin\theta+2\rho'\cos\theta]\\
&=2(\rho')^2\cos^2\theta+[\rho'(\rho''-\rho)-2\rho\rho']\sin\theta\cos\theta-\rho(\rho''-\rho)\sin^2\theta
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
x''(\theta)y'(\theta)&=[(\rho''-\rho)\cos\theta-2\rho'\sin\theta](\rho'\sin\theta+\rho\cos\theta)\\
&=\rho(\rho''-\rho)\cos^2\theta+[\rho'(\rho''-\rho)-2\rho\rho']\sin\theta\cos\theta-2(\rho')^2\sin^2\theta
\end{align*}

Using the proposition stated in the beginning the curvature of $\rho(\theta)$ is given by

\begin{align*}
\kappa(\theta)&=\dfrac{x'(\theta)y''(\theta)-x''(\theta)y'(\theta)}{((x')^2+(y')^2)^{3/2}}=\dfrac{2(\rho')^2-\rho(\rho''-\rho)}{\left((\rho')^2+\rho^2\right)^{3/2}}=\dfrac{2(\rho')^2-\rho\rho''+\rho^2}{\left(\rho^2+(\rho')^2\right)^{3/2}}
\end{align*}